Audio Reconstruction from a normalized spectrogram vector
Is there a way to reconstruct an audio from a normalized spectrogram vector?. I have trained model normalizing the spectrograms and I would like to reconstruct the audio with high quality. I tried using griffin-lim algorithm but the audio reconstructed is far from the original clip. Any directions that you can point me to?
I tried reconstructing using griffin_lim algorithm, I am using tensorflow (I do know its easier to use librosa but its not optimized for using with tensorflow hence i had to use tensorflow). For spectrogram extraction, i use the default tf.signal.stft() and normalize it for training. Now, I want to convert the spectrogram back into audio and this is what i have used:
def griffin_lim(spectrogram, frame_length, frame_step, fft_length, iterations):
spectrogram = tf.cast(spectrogram, tf.complex64)
def invert_spectrogram(spectrogram):
    return tf.signal.inverse_stft(
        spectrogram,
        frame_length=frame_length,
        frame_step=frame_step,
        fft_length=fft_length,
        window_fn=tf.signal.inverse_stft_window_fn(frame_step)
    )

for i in range(iterations):
    reconstructed_waveform = invert_spectrogram(spectrogram)
    spectrogram = tf.signal.stft(reconstructed_waveform, frame_length, frame_step, fft_length)
    spectrogram = tf.complex(tf.math.real(spectrogram), tf.math.imag(spectrogram))
return reconstructed_waveform


This is not really a code question, but more a ML/signal processing question imho. I'd suggest asking that question on a dedicated stackexchange (like DSP or AI). I would probably look into auto-encoders, with an encoder to do the normalization and the decoder to do the de-normalization.
